# transform 'A => F[G[B]]' into 'F[G[A=>B]' scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

Given a function with signature: `A => F[G[B]]`. There are monads instances for `F` and `G` types.

Is it possible to transform it into something with the signature: `F[G[A=>B]`? Is there any general name for such transformation?

In other words what would be the implementation of `prettify2`?

```
def pretiffy(x: String): Future[Option[String]] = Future{if(x == "") None else Some(s">>>$x<<<")}
val pretiffy2: Future[Option[String => String]] = ???
```

Update: I'd appreciate answers using cats or scalaz.

Comment: This is referred to as *higher-kinded types*. You could use `Scalaz` or `Cats` to work with them.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed what I need. How to do this?

Comment: Suppose you have a `String=>List[Option[Integer]]`. You need to produce a `List[Option[String=>Integer]]`.  Can you do that? How long the resulting list would be? How many `None`s would iit contain?

Comment: Thanks, that should be the answer :)

Comment: @pawel.panasewicz Also note that you already run into this if you remove `G` (or `Option` from n.m.'s example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we have a `String=>List[Option[Integer]]`. We need to produce a `List[Option[String=>Integer]]`. How should we approach this? For example, how long the resulting list should be? How many `None`s should it contain?

Obviously these questions have no answers, which means the requested transformation cannot exist for an arbitrary monad (or indeed most monads, as one can ask similar questions about most monads).

Comment: ... which is why the recommendation to look into Scalaz and Cats. Those and similar frameworks generalize the notion of monads so that the `unit` function, `None` in the case `Option` and `Nil` in the case of `List`, can be extracted and used in a genericized way.